# UIButton - Keep text black when touched

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have an iPhone UIButton (Custom) which has a background image and text.

When touched, the image darkens (Good) but the text goes from the set Black to white.

How do I keep the text the same black so that when the button is touched, only the image changes color.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of the times, the following line will do:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If nothing happens, then use either this:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:(UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateNormal)];
```

Or this will do the trick:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

See comments below for reason this answer was edited/expanded to include the 2 separate lines.

Comment: Why was this accepted? It won't work. Touching down on a button only turns on the highlighted state. Buttons don't move into the selected state unless you explicitly instruct them to.

Comment: This way, if he does explicitly instruct the button to go into the selected state, the color will stay black.  Or, he could be subclassing the UIButton and implementing the selected state the way obj-c should have originally. =p

Comment: But it doesn't solve the original question, which was how to keep the text from changing color when he touches the button. Your answer only sets the text color if the button is both selected *and* highlighted.

Comment: [Objective-C Operators and Expressions - Bitwise Operators](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions).  Definitions from UIControl.h `UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0` and  `UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2`.  Bitwise OR should make it so black is the title color if just 1 and when both states are set.

Comment: Nope, it only makes it black if *both* states are set. Just because you use a bitwise OR to combine them doesn't impart the meaning "state a OR state b". In essence, the bitwise OR in this case corresponds to a logical AND.

Comment: @kevinballard Interesting, that kind of defeats the whole purpose of using bitshifted enums as flags.  I'll look into it more when I get back to my computer (on iPhone at the moment).

Comment: Why does that defeat the purpose? It's a bitfield. Some bitfields are used as logical ORs, and some as logical ANDs. This one is a logical AND. `bitfield && state != 0` is the OR version and `bitfield && state == bitfield` is the AND version. UIButton state methods use the latter.

Comment: @kevin But then the object (UIButton in this case) *should* only ever be in 1 state at a time.

Comment: UIButton is in only one state, but if a state doesn't have a definition for a property (e.g. title color), it falls back to inheriting from other states. I don't know the exact fallback behavior, but I would assume it tries to take the "most specific" state (e.g. one with the most bits) that's a sub-state of the current one. If multiple states match, it probably just takes the first one it finds.

Answer (score 5):

`[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]`

Answer (score 0):

```
okButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[okButton addTarget:self action:@selector(isPressingForgetButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[okButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressForgetButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


- (void) isPressingForgetButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * bt = (UIButton *)sender;
    bt.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
- (void) didPressForgetButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * bt = (UIButton *)sender;
    bt.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self gotoUnblockView];
}
```